# Approve folder in document library from Rest API (SharePoint Foundation 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-approval, rest

I am able to approve files easily enough with the url

```
var url = SPAppWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + filePath + "')/Approve(comment='AutoApprove - " + currentdate.getMonth() + "-" + currentdate.getDate() + "-" + currentdate.getYear() + "')?@target='" + rootSite + "'";
```

but doing below fails for folder with error 'Cannot find resource for the request Approve.'

```
var url = SPAppWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folderPath + "')/Approve(comment='AutoApprove - " + currentdate.getMonth() + "-" + currentdate.getDate() + "-" + currentdate.getYear() + "')?@target='" + rootSite + "'";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error since `SP.Folder` resource does not expose `Approve` method (the list of methods for `SP.Folder` resource are listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj245542.aspx))

You could consider the following solution to approve folder:

```
function approveFolder(webUrl,folderUrl,comments){
   var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('" + folderUrl + "')/ListItemAllFields";
   return executeJson(endpointUrl)
   .then(function(data){                 
      var itemPayload = {};
      itemPayload['__metadata'] = {'type': data.d['__metadata']['type']};
      itemPayload['OData__ModerationStatus'] = 0;
      itemPayload['OData__ModerationComments'] = comments;
      var itemUrl = data.d['__metadata']['uri'];
      var headers = {};
      headers["X-HTTP-Method"] = "MERGE";
      headers["If-Match"] =  "*";
      return executeJson(itemUrl,"POST",headers,itemPayload);
   });
}
```

where

```
function executeJson(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
    headers = headers || {};
    method = method || 'GET';
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if(method == "POST") {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  
    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl; // web url
var folderUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/Documents/Archive";


approveFolder(webUrl,folderUrl,'Reviewed')
.done(function(item){
   console.log('Approved');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```